# BinarySearch how to find the value in the array between the two neighbors?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, find, binary-search

I have a sorted array **double**.
The goal is to Find the index in the Array. 
Which contains the value of <= the value of search.

For example the array contains numbers `{0, 5, 12, 34, 100}` with index range [0 .. 4].

Search for the value=25. And I want to get the index=2 (range of occurrences of between 12 and 34)

I do not understand how in this case will run a binary search.

```
   public class MyComparer : IComparer<double>
    {
        public int Compare(double x, double y)
        {
            //<-------- ???
        }
    }

    public double[] spline_x;

    MyComparer cmpc = new MyComparer();
    int i=Array.BinarySearch(spline_x, x, cmpc);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When binary search does not find item in array, it returns a negative number which is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value. Here is the way you can use it to find range:

```
double[] spline_x = { 0D, 5D, 12D, 34D, 100D };
int i = Array.BinarySearch(spline_x, 25);
if (i >= 0)
{
    // your number is in array
}
else
{
    int indexOfNearest = ~i;

    if (indexOfNearest == spline_x.Length)
    {
        // number is greater that last item
    }
    else if (indexOfNearest == 0)
    {
        // number is less than first item
    }
    else
    {
        // number is between (indexOfNearest - 1) and indexOfNearest
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I'm a bit simplified:

   int i=Array.BinarySearch(spline_x, x);
   if (i<0)
   {
    i = ~i;
    i--;
   }
   if (i >= 0)
   {

   }

Comment: @Mixer keep in mind, that after decrementing *i* you can get `-1` of index of last item of array

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with C#, but a naive binary search does the trick, finding the last number <= N, which is the boundary you described in question.

```
int find_last(int num, const vector<int>&v, size_t begin, size_t end) {
  if (begin >= end) {
    return -1;
  }
  size_t mid = (begin + end) / 2;
  if (v[mid] > num) {
    // [mid, end) is bigger than num, the boundary is in [begin, mid)
    return find_last(num, v, begin, mid);
  }
  // v[mid] is qualified as <= N, search [mid+1, end) for
  // approaching a better boundary if exists.
  size_t index = find_last(num, v, mid+1, end);
  return (index == -1 ? mid : index);
}
```